# How to securely transfer data to a external hard drive from an ubuntu machine?

Tags: bash, copy, md5, rsync, verify

I want to transfer data of huge size (each file about 15GB, totally around 2TB) to a new hardrive without loss (corrupt) of the data. How can transfer and verify wheteher data is copied completely to the hard drive?
I tried like:

```
rsync -avP /data/fastq/001q1.fastq.gz 001q1.fastq.gz
```

And in loop as:

```
for i in *.fastq.gz; do
rsync -avP $i /data/external_hdd/$i;
done
```

But how can I validate whether the data is copied completely?

Comment: `cp` then `md5sum` of the original and the copy, and compare.

Comment: @JamesBrown 
Can you help me with the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync` already has internal checks for data integrity, you just need it to "tell" you it completed, for example by adding  `&& echo transfer complete`

If the message is not displayed, it may have failed and the transfer did not complete.
If you want to display a message when it fails instead, it's also possible with  `|| echo transfer failed`

If you want both, the cleanest way is to use an `if` construct:

```
if rsync -avP /data/fastq/ /data/external_hdd/; then
  echo transfer complete
else
  echo transfer failed
fi
```

Comment: I will try this

Answer (score 0):

You should put `""` in `echo`

```
if rsync -avP /data/fastq/ /data/external_hdd/; then
  echo "transfer complete"
else
  echo "transfer failed"
fi
```